# Como fazer contar linha com runquery(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

```
$id= $this->id;
    $consulta = DB::select('select *from locacao where id = ?',[$id]);

    $consulta->count();
```

Tentei assim :(, mas não deu certo o $consulta->count(); só acho coisas referentes ao eloquente, mas não gostei, estou usando esse metodo de runningquery do laravel, como posso saber a qt de linhas retornadas na consulta? :(

```
CODIGO TODO:
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LocacaoBanco {

    public $datalocacao;
    public $datadevolucao;
    public $valorlocacao;
    public $estadodevolucao;
    public $id;

        public function __construct() {

            $this->datalocacao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
            $this->datadevolucao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
            $this->valorlocacao = 5.20;
            $this->estadodevolucao = "nao";
            $this->id = 0;


        }
        public function setRegLocacao() {
                $datalocacao = $this->datalocacao;
                $datadevolucao = $this->datadevolucao;
                $valorlocacao = $this->valorlocacao;
                $estadodevolucao = $this->estadodevolucao;
                $id = $this->id;

            DB::insert('insert into locacao (datalocacao,datadevolucao,valorlocacao,estadodevolucao) values (?,?,?,?,?)',[$datalocacao,$datadevolucao,$valorlocacao,$estadodevolucao,$id]);
            echo "Insercao da tabela locacao executada";

        }
        public function setAtualizaLocacao() {

                $datalocacao = $this->datalocacao;
                $datadevolucao = $this->datadevolucao;
                $valorlocacao = $this->valorlocacao;
                $estadodevolucao = $this->estadodevolucao;
                $id = $this->id;
                DB::update("update locacao SET datalocacao = ?,datadevolucao = ?,valorlocacao=?,estadodevolucao=?,id=? ",[$datalocacao,$datadevolucao,$valorlocacao,$estadodevolucao,$id]);
                echo "locacao atualizada";
        }
        public function getConsultaLocacao() {
            $id= $this->id;
            $consulta = DB::select('select *from locacao where id = ?',[$id]);

            $consulta->count();

        }


}




?>
```

Comment: Gente?? me ajudem por favor

Comment: Lorena você está usando o Laravel errado, é **Complicado** te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar te ajudar da melhor maneira possível, você está tentando usando o Laravel de forma meio "estranha", então vou tentar responder o máximo de coisas que eu ver que achar errado, tudo bom ?

**Primeira questão:**

```
$id= $this->id;
    $consulta = DB::select('select *from locacao where id = ?',[$id]);

    $consulta->count();
```

> O que percebi é que você está colocando toda a consulta dentro do
>   `select()`, mas ele serve apenas para definir quais colunas serão
>   consultadas.

A forma que está usando está um pouco estranha, o correto estaria mais para isso aqui:

```
$consulta = DB::table('locacao')->where('id', $this->id)->count();
```

se você estivesse usando algum model para essa locação ficaria ainda mais fácil.

> O que eu fiz, defini a tabela da busca chamei o método `where()` e
>   defini os parâmetros da consulta.

Espero ter conseguido ajudar.

**Referencias:**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent